# Moving cursor when maxlength in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to move cursor to the next input when the maxlength of the current input is reached.But it's not working.
So when I have 10 letters for 'Name',my cursor must be moved on 'Country'.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="1"  name="Name"   maxlength="10" />
<input type="text" id="2"  name="Country"  maxlength="9" />
<input type="text" id="3" name="Password"   maxlength="8" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("inputs").keyup(function () {
        if (this.value.length == this.maxength) {
          $(this).next('inputs').focus();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Helps if you spell `maxength` correctly

Comment: In addition to the mistyped maxLength it should be $("input") instead of $("inputs") and next("input") instead of next("inputs").